# Offsite backup solution that supports USB external drives?

Tags: backup, online-storage

I am looking for an affordable and simple online backup solution for our server's data. It is a simple file server running windows 7, however all of the data is on an external usb Drobo.

I was hoping to use the Carbonite backup solution, but they do not support external har drives.

Can somebody recommend an online backup service similar to carbonite (in simplicity and price) that will back up our USB drobo?

Thank you

Comment: Title says 'Offsite backup' but the body of the question says 'online' twice.

Comment: Well, I guess an online backup IS off-site...

Comment: Depends on what is meant by online in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jungle Disk](http://www.jungledisk.com/) may work for you.  Jungle Disk was only the backup software and you had to get an Amazon S3 account and pay for storage and bandwidth.  Now I see they have a Business and Personal editions and I'm not sure about all the features and costs of their Business version.

Mozy.com Home version had the same external drive limitation.  I had thought their Pro version allowed it, but I couldn't find out either way on their site.  I did find a way around the external drive limitation by using iSCSI to mount the drive as a local drive, but that isn't something I would recommend for work unless there is no other way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 was in the middle of writing up a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/edrive.html) seems to support External USB drives.

They note that they do not backup network drives or non local drives, due to obvious abuse potential. But at $5/month for unlimited storage(With a free trial), that should be more than adequate.

I have not used Backblaze yet, but I would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: I just realize that you asked this question for a server. I believe that all of the services mentioned (including carbonite) are targeted for home/consumer usage, NOT professional/server use. I don't know which of these software specifically prevents installing on a server OS, but it does go against there terms of service. If you are trying to backup a work machine, you are generally going to be paying per GB.... sorry.

---

There are a number of backup solutions available that are similar to Carbonite ($55/year or $4.59/month for unlimited online backup)

[Mozy](http://mozy.com/) is probably their most similar competitor. Also unlimited data, that does support USB hard drives (as long as they are marked as "fixed". See http://support.mozy.com/docs/en-user-home-win/faq/concepts/external_drives_faq.html). Price is $4.95/month

[CrashPlan](http://b7.crashplan.com/consumer/index.html) is a service that I personally like. It has more options, so it can be *slightly* more difficult to setup, but its certainly not hard. They also allow for simultaneous backup to a local disk for free. They offer unlimited online backup for $54/year or $4.50/month (if you pay for 3years it goes down to $3.47/month)

As minamhere mentioned: [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/) also offers an unlimited backup for $5/month and appears to support external USB disks.

Answer (score 0):

Cyberbackupservice.com will do external usb drives, as long as you choose it in your backup config as a drive to backup.  http://www.cyberbackupservice.com and they have a 30 day trial for upto 100GB of backup capacity.